# How to copy and paste specific paragraphs from multiple Word files using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to retrieve specific paragraphs from hundreds of Word documents.

I have code to select which file to retrieve and then comb my file for a paragraph.

- The paragraph starts after the words "POSITION RESPONSIBILITIES: (List any position specific responsibilities/duties that are not listed on the Job)".
- My paragraph ends before the words "POSITION SPECIFIC".

The code is to copy the entire paragraph to cell(F2). It does not always retrieve my paragraph correctly. It sometimes leaves off the very beginning or cuts off the end.

I have not figured out a way to find the end of the paragraph and have substituted a paragraph number instead. Unfortunately, the paragraph number changes depending on which document is selected.

I also have not figured out a way to loop this so that I may paste each new paragraph in the subsequent rows(F2-->F3-->F4-->etc.).

```vb
Sub WordToExcel()

Dim Document, Word As Object
Dim File As Variant
Dim srchRng As Word.Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

File = Application.GetOpenFilename _
("Word file(*.doc;*.docx;*.txt) ,*.doc;*.docx;*txt", , "Accounts Payable Specialist - Please Select")
If File = False Then Exit Sub

Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Document = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=File, ReadOnly:=True)
Document.Activate

Set srchRng = Word.ActiveDocument.Content

With srchRng.Find
    .Text = "POSITION RESPONSIBILITIES: (List any position specific responsibilities/duties that are not listed on the Job)"

    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
        Dim numberStart As Long
        Dim rnge
        numberStart = Len(srchRng.Text) - 3
        srchRng.MoveEndUntil Cset:="POSITION SPECIFIC"

        Dim myNum As String
        myNum = Mid(srchRng.Text, numberStart)
     
        Set rnge = Document.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Words(numberStart).Start, End:=Document.Paragraphs(29).Range.End)
rnge.Select

        On Error Resume Next
        Word.Selection.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("F2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Document.Close
        Word.Quit (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    End If
End With

Dim val As String
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("F2:F9")

For Each Cell In rng
    val = val & Chr(10) & Cell.Value
Next Cell

With rng
    .Merge
    .Value = Trim(val)
    .WrapText = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat different approach:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim File As Variant
File = Application.GetOpenFilename _
("Word file(*.doc;*.docx;*.txt) ,*.doc;*.docx;*txt", , "Accounts Payable Specialist - Please Select")
If File = False Then Exit Sub
Dim WdApp As New Word.Application, WdDoc As Word.Document, WdRng As Word.Range, XlSht As Excel.Worksheet
Set XlSht = ActiveSheet
With WdApp
  .Visible = False
  Set WdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=File, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  With WdDoc
    With .Range
      With .Find
        .Text = "POSITION RESPONSIBILITIES:*POSITION SPECIFIC"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute
      End With
      If .Find.Found = True Then
        .Start = .Paragraphs.First.Range.End
        .End = .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start
        Set WdRng = .Duplicate
        With WdRng
          With .Find
            .Text = "[^13^l]"
            .Replacement.Text = "¶"
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
          End With
        End With
        .Copy
        With XlSht
          .Paste Destination:=Range("F2")
          .Range("F2").Font.Name = "Tahoma"
          .Range("F2").Replace What:="¶", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart
        End With
      End If
    End With
    .Close False
  End With
  .Quit
End With
Set XlSht = Nothing: Set WdDoc = Nothing: Set WdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

If you want to keep the beginning paragraph, delete/comment-out:

```
.Start = .Paragraphs.First.Range.End
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When running the code i continue to get a Run-time error '438' when it gets to the ".paste" method. I have tried many different tweaks of the code to try and find a solution but have been unsuccessful. Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: Code revised. Try it now.